# Block level copy a NTFS data drive in a Mac Pro to a new, empty drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, parallels-desktop, ntfs

Is there a way I can perform a block level copy of an NTFS data drive (used in Parallels) to a new empty drive?

The source drive is a 750GB NTFS formatted drive used for backing up files from a Windows Parallels VM.

The destination drive is a new 1TB empty drive, which will need to be NTFS format so I can continue backing up files to it.

I considered using the `dd` command but I'm don't know if it'll work and I don't know what the appropriate command is to do this.

Is there a way to do what I'm wanting to do using software in macOS Sierra or do I need to buy something or install a 3rd party software package?

Comment: Are the 0.75 and 1 TB drives real external drives bound to the VM via *VM > Hardware > USB & BT > USB connection preferences...* or virtual disks in Parallels?

Comment: I haven't installed them yet, but they will be internal drive in the Mac Pro. The source (0.75) will be be in Bay 1, and the destination will be in Bay 2. Hmmm, now that I said that out loud, it appears they will need to be a disk image if internal drives. The source is currently inside a USB drive exclosure.

Comment: AFAIR you can also attach them as raw devices in the VM (with a "container disk image/hdd" ). The `dd` approach really depends on how the two disks are attached to the VM...

Comment: Are the drives physical drives that you connect to the VM?